# Windbg stack trace issue

Tags: multithreading, crash, windbg, managed

I am debugging a crash dump of managed code, when using !threads to show all threads here, a couple of threads has Exception field value with various exceptions.

My question is how to identify which exception is the root exception which causes process crash in a quick way? Any ideas why so many threads are associated with Exception value -- I think there should be only one thread (with unhandled exception) which causes process crash, why so many threads shows exception? :-)

thanks in advance,
George

Here is an example of output of a part of !threads, FooException and GooException are my application defined exception type.

48    f 14c4 000000001d8bc4a0      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (0000000093365da0)
  49   10 17e8 000000001acc26d0   200b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (0000000093364670)
  50   11 135c 000000001acc3180   200b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (00000000dd707f70)
  51   12 1740 000000001aca2ec0   200b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (00000000937e8a60)
  52   13  814 000000001aca3970      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA GooException (000000009336c550)
  53   14  6ac 000000001accb010      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (0000000093355f58)
  54   15 1114 000000001accbac0      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA
  56   16  d44 000000001accc570   200b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA GooException (00000000933c0598)
  58   17  ff4 000000001accd020   200b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (00000000a8a39c48)
  59   18  780 000000001accdad0      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA
  60   19  8fc 000000001acce580      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (00000000abd5ff08)
  61   1a  2e8 000000001accf030      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (00000000ac163ea0)
  62   1b 11e8 000000001d8bd010      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (0000000093367c78)
  63   1c 1520 000000001d8bd5e0   200b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA
  64   1d 1330 000000001d8be090      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (00000000937d9540)
  65   1e  7f8 000000001d8beb40      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (000000009339a038)
  66   1f  a70 000000001d8bf5f0      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (00000000937d8b88)
  67   20  150 000000001d8c00a0      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA
  68   21 1628 000000001d8c0b50      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (0000000093355200)
  69   22 1148 000000001d8c1600   200b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA GooException (000000009380ada8)
  70   23 16a8 000000001d8c20b0      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (0000000093365178)
  71   24 1640 000000001d8c2b60      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (0000000093343a78)
  72   25 1568 000000001d8c3610      b020 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000162080     0 MTA FooException (000000009380cc08)

Comment: Perhaps the output of !threads would be useful here?

Comment: Thanks for your good idea Paul, I have added more information. :-)

Answer (score 4):

When you are debugging a dump, you can find the faulting thread by using the **"~"** command and then look for a **"."** next to one of the threads.  Then you change to that thread and run **kb**.  You should see a call to **RaiseException()** in the native callstack.

Also you can run **!clstack** to get the managed call stack once you know the thread of interest.

You can also run **!pe** on the thread to dump the (!PrintException) output.

That should get you most of the way.. feel free to comment and share more data based on the steps I have outlined and we should be able to resolve this quickly

To answer your question, it appears that for a period of time that the exception is on the thread, the !threads output will indicate that.  So it looks like you have alot of excpetions to track down.

**Another technique (that deserves another TAG :-)**

To track down the other exceptions you can use Visual Studion and enable breaking on thrown exception in the UI.  If you are daring, you can run Mdbg and run the following commands to catch the exceptions being thrown

```
Open a VS.NET 2005/2008 Command Prompt
mdbg
>pro //Lists the processes
>a <PID> //attach to the processes
>ca ex //catches all exceptions
>g //go until break
//When it breaks on an exception
>where -v -c 200 // dumps the managed call stack (verbose) with a count of 200 frames
>print //prints out locals on the stack
>g //go to next exception
>de //Detach when done.. process stays running
>q //Quit the debugger
```

The nice thing about **MDbg** is that you can do source level debugging.  (maybe I'll create an **MDbg** tag for these)

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 1):

George2,
   Did you try the command "!analyze -v" ?  Have you loaded the sos dot net debugger extension?  (try the .chain command to see if it's in there).  Analyze -v is very helpful . . .